# QGIS - is it possible add this remote map?

Tags: maps, qgis

I need join this layer in QGIS: 
http://ags.kr-plzensky.cz/arcgis/rest/services/PODKLAD/ortofoto1947_CR/MapServer/

I gave it in ArcGisFeatureServer, but no tiles show. Only this in log:

2018-11-20T09:45:22     WARNING    Tile request error (Status: 200; Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8; Length: 4920; URL: http://ags.kr-plzensky.cz/arcgis/rest/services/PODKLAD/ortofoto1947_CR/MapServer/)

Is it possible to join that layer in QGIS?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202615/adding-arcgis-online-services-to-qgis

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [it should be](https://bl.ocks.org/maptastik/9b0665741a788981276b)

1. Copy the URL you have there
2. In QGIS, click Add Vector Layer
3. In the dialog box, select the Protocol option.
4. Paste the service URL into the URI field
   To the end of the the URL, add: `query?where=objectid+%3D+objectid&outfields=*&f=json`
5. Click Open